# Log Showing Media Player after admod closes

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I realise that the logcat had been showing this repeatedly after showing a interstitial advertisement from admob even after closing it.

```
03-18 10:08:34.988: V/MediaPlayer(25595): message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
03-18 10:08:34.988: V/MediaPlayer(25595): buffering 100
03-18 10:08:34.988: V/MediaPlayer(25595): callback application
03-18 10:08:34.988: V/MediaPlayer(25595): back from callback
03-18 10:08:35.989: V/MediaPlayer(25595): message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
03-18 10:08:35.989: V/MediaPlayer(25595): buffering 100
03-18 10:08:35.989: V/MediaPlayer(25595): callback application
03-18 10:08:35.989: V/MediaPlayer(25595): back from callback
03-18 10:08:36.990: V/MediaPlayer(25595): message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
03-18 10:08:36.990: V/MediaPlayer(25595): buffering 100
03-18 10:08:36.990: V/MediaPlayer(25595): callback application
03-18 10:08:36.990: V/MediaPlayer(25595): back from callback
```

It only happens when there is a media advertisement like `candy crush soda` with the video showing. Is there any way I can close or stop the MediaPlayer in the background running?

I had tried to use

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

When the activity is destroy or when `onAdClose` but it doesn't stop it from running in the background.

Is there anyone have the same problem as me? And does it affect the application if we ignore it totally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the `MediaPlayer` is used, the logs you mention will be shown regardless of your application mode :Debug or Release mode.
Simply put, it is out of your control. 
And in my knowledge it doesn't affect your application.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response :)